# Rules in Firestore Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am setting the rules for my firestore database but I can't understand the meaning of malicious user . If I have the path:
`/junction_user_item/PROVA/items/A23W4....`   where A23W4.. is the uid . For this path I set the following rule:

```
match /junction_user_item/{multiSegment=**}/{userId}{
    allow read: if request.auth != null
    allow write: if request.auth != null
}
```

Each document of this path contains the value 'likes' (each time the document is displayed by any logged-in user, the value can be incremented by 1 if you like the picture:
`likes:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)`

The idea is that under the path `/junction_user_item/PROVA/items/' there is a collection of photos and anyone can like it by editing the document.

Now, what can a malicious user who has logged in do? Can he use that path and increase the 'likes' property by as much as he wants of any document ? I can't put the rule :

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
```

because the documents under that path must be accessible to everyone.

Also how to make sure no one can edit/delete the path?

```
/junction_user_item/PROVA
```

Comment: To avoid users making any changes (delete, change the documents), you can only grant authenticated users the read privilege and negate any write privileges to all users.  That way, only the authenticated users can read the documents, but not be able to edit them or delete them. Do you want the users to change their own files? To what extent do you want the user to have control over the files?

Comment: hello Andrea , I have modified the post a bit to make the idea better. Yes, anyone can edit the documents created by others for that path by incrementing the 'likes' value by 1. But I didn't understand how to make it safe with the rules

Comment: Friendly advice: Your question has several questions and will be difficult to come up with an answer that will cover all your questions.  Fix your question and if necessary open several questions to avoid your question being overlooked or in the worst case scenario being closed.  Here is a good guide explaining what I just mentioned. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I suggest re-thinking the logic; the question states that *any logged-in user* can increment the count*. Meaning that *every user* must have write privileges to the field that stores the like count and there's no traceability on which user incremented it. That, in itself is an issue. One option is to store a ref to the image within that users folder; that enables the total number of likes to be determined, which users liked and also prevent a user from incrementing the value if that ref already exists within that users document. There are other options as well but rules are not a filter.